# SQL temp date table generation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wonder is there a way to generate a temp table containing dates but using between, because I have to use such a construction.

```
between Convert(datetime, '2022-01-01T00:00:00.000', 126) and Convert(datetime, '2022-03-04T23:59:59.998', 126)
```

I mean it should use between not StartDate,EndDate.

Comment: I don't follow what you are asking here. `BETWEEN` is a boolean operator; `{Scalar value} BETWEEN {Lower value} AND {Greater value}`. You need to elaborate here.

Comment: No, there isn't. You can build one using say sys.objects.

Comment: Use / build a calendar table. You can search the internet using that phrase to find many suggestions. `Convert(datetime, '2022-03-04T23:59:59.998', 126)` Don't do this - use an exclusive upper boundary to avoid precision issues.

Comment: Nobody ever _has to_ use `BETWEEN` for date range queries, and here I explain why it's such a bad idea: [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Wow, at least one article I do not agree with... (because it's opinion based)

Comment: @Luuk what part is opinion-based? That it's safe to use `BETWEEN` for `date` but you still shouldn't?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: "For one, the meaning of the word in English does not always match the meaning of the operator in T-SQL"   I, personally never compare any language with English.  A language must follow its own rules, especially if it is a computer (related) language.

Comment: @Luuk My point was that people - say, co-workers discussing query requirements - will _talk_ about things in one way ("between the beginning and the end of February") and that word in English (or whatever language they speak) means something slightly different in T-SQL (because "the end of February" is a somewhat non-deterministic thing). That's not an opinion and not really something to disagree with

Comment: Aside: Don't try to finesse the end of a day (`Convert(datetime, '2022-03-04T23:59:59.998', 126)`), just use `<` the next date. You won't have to chase down the one time that something fails because the datatype was changed, e.g. from `DateTime` to `DateTime2`, that has a different precision and some value landed in that tiny window just before midnight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option which I think performs better than a recursive CTE

```
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT 0 AS I
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, '20220101', '20220304')) 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3),
Dates AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.I, '20220101') AS Date
    FROM Tally T)
SELECT D.Date
into #tmpDates
FROM Dates D
```

**EDIT**
I always have a calendar table in my database, so I can just join on that. This performs quite well and the queries are much easier

Comment: I would just use 1 permanent table with datetimes, and not a temp table which need to be re-created, or use 1 WITH statement:  `with ctedates as ( select CAST('2022-01-01' as DATETIME) as Date  union all SELECT DateADD(DAY,1,Date) FROM ctedates WHERE Date < '2022-03-04' ) SELECT * FROM ctedates;`

Comment: @Luuk recursive CTE with date ranges gets a little complex if the range can be more than 100 days. Try yours [with an end date of April 15](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5f295a118aa1da0165ad5cc6ce2d7227), for example.

Comment: @AaronBertrand That's why I created a permanten table (named `dates`) with all the dates from `2020-01-01` -  `2042-06-05`  (or should i say BETWEEN ), and when I ever think the endDate is to close, I do `insert into dates select dateadd(DAY, (select count(*) from dates) + row_number() over(order by d)-1, (select min(d) from dates)) from dates;`

Comment: @Luuk Yes, I was just adding context to your suggestion to use WITH instead of a permanent table.

Answer (score 0):

An option for a getting the temp table.  Not 100% it will do what's required.  Hope this helps though.

```
 DECLARE  @start_date date = '2022-01-01',
         @end_date date = '2022-03-04'

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT @start_date as DateRet
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(day,1,dateRet) as date)
FROM cte
WHERE dateret < @end_date
)

SELECT *
into #tmpDates
FROM cte
```

Comment: A Tally would be significantly faster approach over an rCTE; especially with larger date ranges.